# OpenNI: "Open failed: Device is in safe mode. Cannot start any stream!"

Tags: c++, linux, usb, openni, primesense

I'm using OpenNi with a primesense sensor to get depth image. *NiViwer* sample works fine, but if the sensor is connected before Linux booting, when I run *NiViewer* or any other program using *OpenNi*, it exits with this error:

***Open failed: Device is in safe mode. Cannot start any stream!***

This is the ful log:

```
      522 INFO       OpenNI version is 1.2.0 (Build 7)-Linux-x86 (May 15 2011 10:29:37)
      572 INFO       Filter Info - minimum severity: VERBOSE, masks: ALL
      704 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Script: OpenNI/OpenNI/1.2.0.7
      983 VERBOSE    Checking /opt/OpenNI/lib/libnimMockNodes.so...
     3240 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. ProductionNode: OpenNI/Mock/1.2.0.7
     3297 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Generator: OpenNI/Mock/1.2.0.7
     3375 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. MapGenerator: OpenNI/Mock/1.2.0.7
     3414 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Device: OpenNI/Mock/1.2.0.7
     3447 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Depth: OpenNI/Mock/1.2.0.7
     3483 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. IR: OpenNI/Mock/1.2.0.7
     3518 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Image: OpenNI/Mock/1.2.0.7
     3551 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Audio: OpenNI/Mock/1.2.0.7
     3589 VERBOSE    Checking /opt/OpenNI/lib/libnimCodecs.so...
     5219 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Codec: OpenNI/16zP/1.2.0.7
     5270 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Codec: OpenNI/16zT/1.2.0.7
     5299 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Codec: OpenNI/Im8z/1.2.0.7
     5372 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Codec: OpenNI/JPEG/1.2.0.7
     5402 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Codec: OpenNI/NONE/1.2.0.7
     5434 VERBOSE    Checking /opt/OpenNI/lib/libnimRecorder.so...
     6910 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Recorder: OpenNI/Recorder/1.2.0.7
     6964 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Player: OpenNI/Player/1.2.0.7
     6994 VERBOSE    Checking /opt/OpenNI/lib/libXnCore.so...
     8106 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Script: OpenNI/OpenNI/1.2.0.7
     8135 WARNING    A Generator with the same description already exists!
     8148 WARNING    Failed to add generator 0 from module '/opt/OpenNI/lib/libXnCore.so'
     8163 VERBOSE    Checking /opt/OpenNI/lib/libXnDDK.so...
    13802 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Script: OpenNI/OpenNI/1.2.0.7
    13836 WARNING    A Generator with the same description already exists!
    13850 WARNING    Failed to add generator 0 from module '/opt/OpenNI/lib/libXnDDK.so'
    13865 VERBOSE    Checking /opt/OpenNI/lib/libXnDeviceFile.so...
    16408 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Player: PrimeSense/File/5.0.2.3
    16460 VERBOSE    Checking /opt/OpenNI/lib/libXnDeviceSensorV2.so...
    20778 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Device: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.0.2.3
    20833 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Depth: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.0.2.3
    20870 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.0.2.3
    20902 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. IR: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.0.2.3
    20934 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Audio: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.0.2.3
    20963 VERBOSE    Checking /opt/OpenNI/lib/libXnFormats.so...
    21066 VERBOSE    Found exported production node. Script: OpenNI/OpenNI/1.2.0.7
    21082 WARNING    A Generator with the same description already exists!
    21093 WARNING    Failed to add generator 0 from module '/opt/OpenNI/lib/libXnFormats.so'
    21410 INFO       Creating node 'Script1' of type Script: OpenNI/OpenNI/1.2.0.7...
    21741 VERBOSE    Requested to create a node of type Depth...
    21875 VERBOSE    Initializing USB...
    22046 INFO       USB is initialized.
    34087 INFO       Creating node 'Device1' of type Device: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.0.2.3...
    57436 WARNING    Server returned an error: Device is in safe mode. Cannot start any stream!
    58380 INFO       Destroying node 'Script1'
Open failed: Device is in safe mode. Cannot start any stream!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Unplug and re-plug solves the problem**, but I need it to work without this trick.

I suppose this problem is about usb module. I've tested this with kernel 2.6.39 and 3.0.6

The error seems to happen here: *libXnDeviceSensorV2.so* **XnSensorFirmware.cpp**

```
XnStatus XnSensorFirmware::Init(XnBool bReset)
{
    XnStatus nRetVal = XN_STATUS_OK;

    // check current mode
    XnUInt16 nMode;
    nRetVal = XnHostProtocolGetMode(m_pDevicePrivateData, nMode);
    XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);

    if (bReset)
    {
        // check if safe mode
        if (nMode == XN_HOST_PROTOCOL_MODE_SAFE_MODE)
        {
            XN_LOG_WARNING_RETURN(XN_STATUS_DEVICE_SAFE_MODE, XN_MASK_DEVICE_SENSOR, "Device is in safe mode. Cannot start any stream!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved updating firmware to V1.06: http://www.openni.org/Downloads/OpenNIModules.aspx

Comment: Hey bro, I'm kind of bumping into the same problem. Mine is a little different. Saying that parameter is incorrect. Then the log file is the same as yours. Actually, I've tried to update firmwares. But it doesn't work. Please offer me some solutions if it's not a bother.

Comment: What product are you using?